# Arrow function with conditionals not returning all elements of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions, ecmascript-2016

I have an array like the following: `var arr = ['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']];`

While trying to return each element by using the arrow function, it returns `undefined` as the third element, instead of the elements values. I've attempted to restructure it, but none of then return all the elements of both arrays. I could use a for loop, do the logic to push each element, but I want to understand and learn how to use arrow functions for cases like this.

```
arr.map(e => {
 if(typeof(e) == "object"){
    e.map(t => t)
  } else{ return e; }
})
```

Will really appreciate some clarification in this matter. The expected result is an array like the following: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].

Comment: expected output ?

Comment: `e.map()` is not `return`ed from `.map()`. `two'` is not a valid string.

Comment: it returns another array, if it is "object" , so there should be return - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZPzBZR?editors=1010

Comment: To make the question a bit more clear. What I want to achieve is to obtain an array like ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].

Comment: Look at [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: flat does the job nicely, although I still want to understand where is the error in the code.

Comment: @Joel Have your read the above comments? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857462/arrow-function-with-conditionals-not-returning-all-elements-of-array/54857587?noredirect=1#comment96486462_54857462 `e.map()` will return an `Array`, not flatten the array. Can you update the question to include the expected output? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map()` is not designed and implemented to flatten an array. Even if `.map()` did flatten an array `e.map(t => t)` is not `return`ed from `.map()` callback function at the code at the question.

```
arr.map(e => {
 if(typeof(e) == "object"){
    e.map(t => t) // no value is `return`ed here
  } else{ return e; }
})
```

There are a variety of approaches and `Array` methods that can be used to flatten an `Array`, including `.flat()`, `.flatMap()` and `.concat()`, e.g., see [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce to return all elements of array within array

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']];

console.log(arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
  typeof(v) == 'object' ? acc.push(...v) : acc.push(v)
  return acc
}, []))
```

codepen -  https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NJKdKv

Comment: What is the issue with the code at the question? What is the expected result?

Comment: as OP mentioned "I've attempted to restructure it, but none of then return all the elements of both arrays." , displaying all elements to one array instead of arrays with in array

Comment: Did not read that as the clear requirement. The two issues with the code at the question are the syntax error in the input array, and `e.map()` is not `return`ed from the function passed to `.map()`

Comment: @guest271314, OP has commented the expected output to single array

Comment: If that is the case `let res = arr.flat()`

Comment: flat() not supported in IE, yes for modern browsers, my solution works for IE and modern browsers

Comment: Why would an individual still be using ie when FOSS browsers are available for free as in beer?  `let res = [].concat(...arr)`